I can't show the same data in Android YCharts
I'm currently working on an Android app using Jetpack Compose and the co.yml.charts library to render a line chart. The problem I'm facing is that when all y values in my dataset are identical, the chart does not render correctly. It seems to fail to display the line chart entirely or displays a very thin line which is hard to notice.



